# How to create range input with custom shape track without JS

Tags: css, html, input, cross-browser

I want to create a range input that has a track bar shaped like a triangle, much like many volume inputs appear. Here is an example.

[image]

I have read this useful guide to styling the input, but it does not have information on changing the shape of the track bar.

I do not want to use a custom range slider with JS that alters the real input, I want to use the actual range input itself. It should also be mostly cross browser.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot reliably change the shape of the track bar itself in a cross browser manner, but you can hide the track bar and position an element or image behind it. Here is an example of this being done.

**HTML**

```
<input type="range" class="font-size-selector pd-select" id="font_size_selector" min="12" value="20" max="100" step="1">
<span class="triangle-range-background-slider"></span>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Trangle */
.triangle-range-background-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -27px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg'); 
  background-size: 100% auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Input to work with triangle */
input[type=range] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

You could also use a CSS shape instead by removing the background image and placing this logic in there in it's place.

```
.triange-range-background-slider {
    position: relative; 
    display: block; 
    margin-top: -27px; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 100px solid #3071a9; 
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    z-index: 1; 
}
```

Rest of the CSS is the Hide and Thumb from the CSS-Tricks link you provided.

https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

**Hide Input CSS**

```
  /* Hide */
  input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
    width: 100%; /* Specific width is required for Firefox. */
    background: transparent; /* Otherwise white in Chrome */
  }

  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }

  input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none; /* Removes the blue border. You should probably do some kind of focus styling for accessibility reasons though. */
  }

  input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;

    /* Hides the slider so custom styles can be added */
    background: transparent; 
    border-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
  }
```

**Thumb Input CSS**

```
  /* Thumb */
  /* Special styling for WebKit/Blink */
  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 36px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    // margin-top: -14px; /* You need to specify a margin in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE it is automatic */
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d; /* Add cool effects to your sliders! */
  }

  /* All the same stuff for Firefox */
  input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 36px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  /* All the same stuff for IE */
  input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 36px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Comment: Great code, thanks! There is just one small typo that had me scratching my head for a while: In the second CSS snippet, it says "triange" instead of "triangle", so the code isn't active when it should.